# How to use strptime to convert timestamp string with milliseconds to time object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strptime

I need to use `strptime` to convert a timestamp string with milliseconds to a Time object.

A work around is using `parse`:

```
t= Time.parse('29 Sep 2013 12:25:00.367')
=> 2013-09-29 12:25:00 -0400
```

But it is very important for my code to use `strptime`, because I want to be able to pass multiple types of format including: "HH:MM", "HH", etc. through the function.

I can do it with nanoseconds like this:

```
Time.strptime("12:34:56:789434", "%H:%M:%S:%N")
=> 2016-03-16 12:34:56 +0100
```

I want something like this:

```
Time.strptime("12:34:56:789", "%H:%M:%S:%[insert magic letter that represent milliseconds]")
```

My thought is that there must be a way to do it with milliseconds as well.

Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `%L`.

Refer to Ruby's [DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you can update to Ruby 1.9.3, it supports this using `%3N`:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime